How to dis associate subnet from NATGateway using Azure SDK
I am using this method to associate NATGateway to a subnet.

            ArmClient azure = this.azureProvider.GetAzureClient(resourceTenantId, subscriptionId);

            var subnetId = SubnetResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, vNetName, subnetName);

            SubnetResource subnetResource = await azure.GetSubnetResource(subnetId).GetAsync();

            subnetResource.Data.NatGatewayId = ResourceIdentifier.Parse(natGatewayId);

            await subnetResource.UpdateAsync(waitUntil: WaitUntil.Completed, data: subnetResource.Data);

But I do not know how to disassociate it.
To disassociate it, if I use
            SubnetResource subnetResource = await azure.GetSubnetResource(subnetId).GetAsync();

            subnetResource.Data.NatGatewayId = null;

            await subnetResource.UpdateAsync(waitUntil: WaitUntil.Completed, data: subnetResource.Data);

Azure will throw exception "error":{"code":"InvalidRequestFormat","message":"Cannot parse the request.","details":[{"code":"MissingJsonReferenceId","message":"Value for reference id is missing. Path properties.natGateway."}] since the resourceId cannot be null.


How to Disassociate Subnet from NAT Gateway using Azure SDK

According to this MS-Document, disassociating the subnet from the NAT Gateway can be done by either through Azure portal or using Azure CLI commands.
Here is the Azure CLI command to disassociate the subnet from the NAT Gateway:
Command:
az network vnet subnet update --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <subnet-name> --vnet-name <vnet-name> --nat-gateway null

Output:
az network vnet subnet update --resource-group vxxx --name xx --vnet-name vxxx --nat-gateway null
{
  "addressPrefix": "10.xxx/24",
  "delegations": [],
  "etag": "W/\"1059xxx4092f\"",
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet678/subnets/default",
  "name": "default",
  "networkSecurityGroup": {
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/sampnat",
    "resourceGroup": "v-vsettu-mindtree"
  },
  "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "NetworkSecurityGroupEnabled",
  "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "resourceGroup": "vxe",
  "serviceEndpoints": [
    {
      "locations": [
        "eastus",
        "westus",
        "westus3"
      ],
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
      "service": "Microsoft.Storage"
    }
  ],
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
}


Portal:

Reference:
az network vnet subnet | Microsoft Learn

Thanks, but I need to do this in C# using new Azure SDK, ex Azure.ResourceManager.Network package. However, not found suitable method so far.

As of know, we can able to do in Azure cli commands or portal only.

I understand you are trying to diss-associate the NAT Gateway from the subnet using Azure dotnet SDK.
As you have correctly understood that this is currently not supported via dotnet SDK.
If it helps, I was able to find work around in this case. The workaround is to invoke Management REST API Subnets - Create Or Update via code.
I was successful in diss-associating the NAT Gateway using the REST API above and below is the code I implemented (the code is in crude state and can be enhanced).

The first step here is to Register your client application with
Microsoft Entra ID so that you can fetch the bearer token to
authenticate the REST API call
Perform Subnets - Get REST API call to get the current
configuration of the subnet.
Remove the natGateway property from the configuration response above
(setting it to null does not work so we have to completely remove the
property).
Perform the Subnets - Create Or Update API call to diss-associate the
NatGateway.

Code:
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace AzureRestApiListSub
{

    class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Azure AD application details
            string clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            string tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            // Azure REST API endpoint
            string apiVersion = "2023-09-01";
            string endpoint = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version={apiVersion}";

            {
                // Set up the authentication context
                var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(clientId)
                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
                    .Build();

                string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };

                // Authenticate and acquire an access token
                var authResult = await confidentialClientApplication
                    .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                string accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;

                var url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/subnets/xxxxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2023-09-01";

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        //Invoke GET request first

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //Parse JSON and remove the natGateway property
                JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
                JObject header = (JObject)jo.SelectToken("properties");
                header.Property("natGateway").Remove();
                string jsonpost = jo.ToString();
                var content = new StringContent(jsonpost, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                Console.Write(jsonpost);
                Console.WriteLine();
                using HttpResponseMessage update = await client.PutAsync(url, content);
                Console.WriteLine("Request with status code: " + update.StatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
}

I was able to implement it on my end

With associated NAT Gateway:

After the code is executed, the association is removed

I understand this not exactly a perfect workaround and I will report the limitation to the NAT Gateway Team.
Hope this helps!

Thanks, ChaitanyaN, I will use this rest api to temp mitigate my issue. thanks a lot.
